# BO Webi - Need Variable to Remove Nulls From Results

Tags: business-objects

I'm looking to create a variable that will take the take the numeric value for a dimension. I tried removing Nulls in my query details, but that won't work because some results only have a Null value (see screenshot) and I was losing results that way.

I also need the variable for use in a cross tab table so I can do a count of each acuity level. I tried creating a Max variable on the acuity field **=Max([Acuity Level])**. That works for the main tab, but it doesn't work in a cross tab table. Please see attached screenshots for more details.

[image]

**Acuity Crosstab**

[image]

Column: Acuity Level

Row: Tracking Date
**=FormatDate([Start Tracking Date & Time];"MM/dd/yyyy")**

Body: # of Patients
**=Count([Financial Number])**

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you want. Can you mock up your expected result in Excel?

Comment: I am looking to remove the extra rows that have a Null in them. There are a few that only have a Null value, so I can't remove all Nulls. I'm including a picture of the results I'd like to get.

Answer (score 0):

First off I created a [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/DeysnoNf) with your test data so I could drop into a free-hand SQL query so I have an example with which I can work. I added **Row Number** to maintain the row order of your data.

[image]

My approach requires three variables. A different approach may be possible requiring less variables or the formulas in the variables could be consolidated. However, I like to keep them separated for better understanding of the logical progression and better maintainability.

**Var Acuity Level Adjusted** gets set to -1 if the **Acuity Level** is Null and otherwise leave it as is just to make it easier to deal with...

```
=If(IsNull([Acuity Level]); -1; [Acuity Level])
```

**Var Max Acuity Level** is the greatest value of **Var Acuity Level Adjusted** within each combination of **Patient Name** and **Encounter Type**. This is called a [calculation context](https://michaelwelter.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/removing-the-confusion-from-calculation-contexts/). I do not understand the nuances of this topic well enough to explain why what I have below works, but it does. I refer to that previous link a lot. Also, this is why it was important that I picked -1 to replace Null.

```
=Max([Var Acuity Level Adjusted]) In ([Patient Name]; [Encounter Type])
```

**Var Max Filter** flags the row where the first two variables are equal. This variable is necessary because you cannot filter based on one object relative to another object.

```
=If([Var Acuity Level Adjusted] = [Var Max Acuity Level]; 1; 0)
```

Now if I add those variables it looks like this...

[image]

Then we can add a filter to only show the records where **Var Max Filter = 1**. You can hide the extra columns or even delete them from the table.

[image]

Hope you can apply this to your situation.

Comment: I got it to work, thank you so much! Is there any way to use those variables to create a cross tab? I need to get a count of each acuity level by day. I haven't been able to get that to work. It won't let me post a picture in the comments, so I'll add a screenshot to the main post. The screenshot is the acuity level field (the original dimension that contains the extra Nulls). The rows are the tracking date, and the body is the number of patients (count of financial number).

Comment: I don't recall a crosstab being part of the original question. So while I believe my answer address the original question it does not look like it does now due to the additional requirement of the crosstab. It preferable to post a new question since it seems you do have a new question. Along with that post your sample data in text for and/or as I did in the [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/DeysnoNf).

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I did list it in my original post, but it was in the second paragraph. It likely got lost focusing on the first part of the request. I will post it as a new question. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: No worries. I'll be on the lookout for your new question.